# R JAGS: Dimension mismatch

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

I am trying to run a model in JAGS but I got the following error:

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
RUNTIME ERROR:
Cannot insert node into m[1]. Dimension mismatch
```

The model I specified is

```
model = "model
    {
      for (i in 1:N) {
        z[i] ~ dnorm(m[i],tau)
        m[i] <- beta0 + beta1*x + beta2*y
      }
      beta0 ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-3)
      beta1 ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-3)
      beta2 ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-3)
      tau ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
    }"
```

Then I specify the data and the initial values. Finally, I run the model.

```
data = list(z = wolfcamp$data, x = wolfcamp$coords[,1], y = wolfcamp$coords[,2], N = length(wolfcamp$data))

parameters=c("beta0","beta1","beta2","tau")
init1 = list(beta0 = 0, beta1 = 0, beta2 = 0, tau = 0)
init2 = list(beta0 = 1, beta1 = 1, beta2 = 1, tau = 1)
initial.values=list(init1, init2)

model1=jags(data=data, inits=initial.values,
            parameters.to.save=parameters,
            model.file=textConnection(model),
            n.chains=2,
            n.burnin=1000,
            n.iter=11000)
```

Can you help me? Do you know why I get this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not indexing through the vectors `x` and `y`, which causes a dimension mismatch.

Change this line:

`m[i] <- beta0 + beta1*x + beta2*y`

to this:

`m[i] <- beta0 + beta1*x[i] + beta2*y[i]`

and you should be good to go (so long as `x` and `y` are of length `N`)